# Move chart point label to another position and connect them with an arrow

Tags: c#, charts, label, point

I want to add 26 points into chart and label them from a to z.

How do I move the label to a nearby position from its original position and how to use an arrow or other symbols to connect the label and corresponding point? The demo chart looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataPoint` `Labels` are being placed pretty much **automatically** and you have only very few options to influence their position.

There are `SmartLabels` but they only allow you to control the behaviour when it comes to **avoiding them to overlap**.

So I think instead of `Labels` you will have to resort to [Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Infact to replicate your image you need one [LineAnnotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.lineannotation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and one [TextAnnotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.textannotation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) per `DataPoint` you want labelled, anchored to that `DataPoint`..:

[image]

Lets assume you are adding the `DataPoints` to your `Series S1`one by one:

```
int p = S1.Points.AddXY(yourXValue, yourYValue);
string s = yourLabelText;
DataPoint dp = S1.Points[p];
```

Now you need to create one `TextAnnotation`, or to be precise a [RectangleAnnotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.rectangleannotation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is a subclass of `TextAnnotation` allowing for background and creating a border:

```
RectangleAnnotation ta = new RectangleAnnotation();
ta.AnchorDataPoint = dp;
ta.AnchorOffsetX = 5;     // *
ta.AnchorOffsetY = 3;     // *
ta.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
ta.Text = s;
chart1.Annotations.Add(ta);
```

Note how I set the positioning here (*) to move the annotation a little up and right. The numbers are **not pixels but percentages** of the chart size. You need to experiment a little to find values you like. The Advantage is that the distance will scale when you resize or zoom the chart.

Now we add the arrow:

```
LineAnnotation la = new LineAnnotation();
la.SetAnchor(dp);
la.AnchorOffsetX = 0.5;   // (**)
la.AnchorOffsetY = -0.5;  // (**)
la.StartCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.Arrow;
la.Width =    ta.AnchorOffsetX - la.AnchorOffsetX;
la.Height = - ta.AnchorOffsetY + la.AnchorOffsetY;  // (***)           
chart1.Annotations.Add(la);
```

(**)  I move the starting point a little off the `DataPoint` so the arrow won't overlap the circle of the point.

(***) Note that the height needs to point upward from the point, so it is negative!

You will want to fine-tune some of the numbers..

Comment: I took several hours to find a solution with label and found nothing helpful. But with annotation it works like a charm. Next time maybe I should think more flexibly. Anyway thanks so much!