# Repositioning chart point label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I have a Chart control that contains multiple overlapping Line series like this:

[image]

As you can see, the labels of the intersection points of the lines overlap the lines themselves. I tried using the following to no avail:

```
intersectPoints.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
intersectPoints.SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false;
```

I'm pretty sure this is because `MarkerOverlapping` only applies to Markers in the series the label belongs to.

I'm looking for how to accomplish any one of several solutions:

1) Manually adjust x-y position of Point label
2) Increase opacity of label so that it appears "above" overlapping lines
3) Use some other SmartLabelStyle tool.
4) If no other solution is available, possibly overwriting the draw method for the chart?

Comment: To make label positionable see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191246/move-chart-point-label-to-another-position-and-connect-them-with-an-arrow/36197745#36197745) - But you can also set the `somePointOrSeries.LabelBackColor = Color.yourChoice`..

Comment: Thank you, that worked exactly as I wanted!